# How can I include custom content with a form element in a page?

Tags: web-part, form

I have been trying to use the HTML Form Webpart and going into the `Source Editor...`

Below if the form I am trying to paste in:

```
<FORM onsubmit="return CheckForm()" method=post name=ttc action=https://www.securevcheck.com/?id=nevadattc&amp;template=nevadattc><INPUT value=nevadattc type=hidden name=customprocess> 
<TABLE bgColor=#e8f4e8>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD><FONT size=2 face=arial>Enter the<BR><B>Parcel Number</B> or<BR>the <B>Category &amp; Acct. Number</B></FONT><BR><BR></TD>
<TD><INPUT size=25 name=parcel><BR><BR></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD><FONT size=2 face=arial>Confirm the<BR><B>Parcel Number</B> or<BR>the <B>Category &amp; Acct. Number</B></FONT><BR><BR></TD>
<TD><INPUT onblur="return checkPw(this)" size=25 name=confirm_parcel><BR><BR></TD></TR><!--NEW FIELD TJ... THE ONE WE USE FOR THE BILL NUMBER--->
<TR>
<TD><FONT size=2 face=arial>Enter the <B>Bill No.</B></FONT><BR><BR></TD>
<TD><INPUT size=10 name=bill><BR><BR></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD><FONT size=2 face=arial>Enter <B>Tax Amt</B>.</FONT><BR><BR></TD>
<TD align=right>$ &nbsp;<INPUT name=amount><BR><BR></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><INPUT type=hidden name=memo> <INPUT type=hidden name=memo2> <INPUT value="Continue to Secure Check Form" type=submit> </FORM>
```

When I paste it in I get some weird javascript errors and then I can't get out of the web part edit panel.  Are we allowed to include this type of content in a page?  If so, what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net (which is the technology SharePoint is built on) does not support multiple FORM elements in a page, which is why you are getting all sorts of errors.

That said, there are a few options that come to mind:

1. Include this form as an iFrame via the Page Viewer Web Part
2. Incorporate jQuery in the page and have it [fetch the requested
   data](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) itself rather than by using a FORM POST.  It doesn't have to be jQuery, but that is probably the simplest way
3. Create a custom Web Part that contains this functionality